# why does my treemap is not sorted in java?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have a treemap:

```
private Map<String, Integer> dataMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

and later in the code I have the following part:

```
for (String item : data) {
    JSONObject itemJson = new JSONObject(item);
    System.out.println("-- before " + itemJson.getString("dataLabel") + " " + itemJson.getInt("dataValue"));
    dataMap.put(itemJson.getString("dataLabel"), itemJson.getInt("dataValue"));
}

for(String data : dataMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("-- after " + data);
}
```

The first loop displays sorted elements, such as:

```
-- before January 1
-- before February 2
-- before March 3
-- before April 4
.
.
.
```

but the second loop mixes the order:

```
-- after April
-- after February
-- after January
-- after March
.
.
.
```

Why so? and how can I get sorted results on the second loop? And by sorted I mean the same order as I was adding them during the first loop? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) sorts the entries by key, not by value. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. **The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys** (this is your case), or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

The output is correct because the strings are sorted alphabetically.

> how can I get sorted results on the second loop? And by sorted I mean the same order as I was adding them during the first loop?

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead, because stores the entries according to the order they were inserted. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. **This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)**. Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.

Comment: how can I keep the original order? I tried to use the `HashMap`, but the result was similar

Comment: Thank you, that works and explains everything, I will mark it as an answer as soon as I'm allowed to :)

Answer (score 0):

The `keySet()` method is used to get a Set view of the keys contained in this map.

```
for (String data : dataMap.keySet())
```

That gives you the keys.

Now in that loop, get each value from the `dataMap` using the key (`data`), and print it.

check following example

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> data: dataMap.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println("Key: " + data.getKey() + ". Value: " + data.getValue());
}
```

**or**

`HashMap` does not define any particular ordering of its element. Therefore the "reverse" order isn't defined either.

For a `TreeMap`, you can use [`descendingMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap%28%29).